# merge two rows and search in

Tags: mysql, merge, concatenation

I've used this MySQL query to get data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.username
FROM posts A, members B
WHERE B.status=1
AND (A.USERID=B.USERID AND A.title LIKE '%myquery%' AND B.public='1' AND A.type = 'update' )
order by A.ID desc limit 0, 10
```

this works to search title row, but i need to search into title and msg row, how to "merge" (?) these two rows into one and make my query?

this is my basic schema.

```
----------------------------
ID |  title  | msg ...     |
----------------------------
 1 | example | hello there |  example data.
```

PS. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question

you can use the **OR**

```
... AND (A.title LIKE '%myquery%' OR A.msg LIKE '%myquery%') ...
```

Comment: you can use DISTINCT(A.id) , ITS NOT help ? what you get exactly ?

Comment: not work, any idea?
the query is for a search box, original query to search in titles, original but change A.title for A.msg to seearch in msg. what am looking for is a way to search in all "post" (title+msg) and show has unique result.

Comment: CAN YOU SHOW THE RESULT with the OR ANSWER ?

Comment: did you run this ?  SELECT DISTINCT A.*, B.username
FROM posts A, members B
WHERE B.status=1
AND (A.USERID=B.USERID AND (A.title LIKE '%myquery%' OR A.msg LIKE '%myquery%' ) AND B.public='1' AND A.type = 'update' )
order by A.ID desc limit 0, 10